# SQL Join and Count returns unexpected match

Tags: mysql, sql

**tbl1**

```
 type|price
 ----------
 1   | 10
 2   | 15
```

**tbl2**

```
 type|expires
 ----------
 1   | 2015-01-01
 1   | 2017-01-01
 1   | 2017-01-01
 2   | 2015-01-01
 2   | 2017-01-01
```

I'd like a query that returns data about a given type in `tbl1`, and the number of current (non-expired) records of that type in `tbl2`. Here is my query:

```
select tbl1.*,
count(if(tbl2.expires > now(),1,null)) current
from tbl1 left join tbl2
on tbl1.type=tbl2.type
where tbl1.type = 1
```

As expected, it returns:

```
type|price|current
1   | 10  | 2
```

However, when I ask for a non existent type, I expect 0 result. However, if I replace the type in the query to `3`, I get:

```
type|price|current
NULL|NULL | 0
```

Please help me understand

1. How does that record match the query? (I expected an empty result set)
2. How to get the behavior I expect? (ie no result for non-existent `type`)

[**Live demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6db6c1/4)

Comment: Your `tbl1` table does not have any data for `type` of 3, so it cannot appear in the result set.  If you want 3 to appear, you will need to bring in this data from somewhere else.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen. I wasn't expecting to see a `type 3` in the results. I expect there to be 0 result when I search for type `3`, but 1 result is returned. That's what I don't get.

Comment: Using an aggregate function like `count` without a `group by` clause returns **always** exactly one row.

Comment: And consider this output pattern `NULL|NULL | 0` as `0 rows found`

Comment: @1000111 Thank you.  Yes that's easy to do from the PHP side that consumes the output; it doesn't answer either of the two questions I had though (from the OP)

Comment: I just edited my answer and tested it in the Fiddle. It works as needed (i.e. null result when type=3, correct result when type = 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an aggregate function like `count` without a `group by` clause returns **always** exactly one row.

A work-around is to wrap your query in a subquery and check for `type` again in the outer query:

```
select *
from (
   select tbl1.*,
          count(if(tbl2.expires > now(),1,null)) current
   from tbl1 
   left join tbl2 on tbl1.type=tbl2.type
   where tbl1.type = 3) as t
where type = 3
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6db6c1/9)

Comment: Hi Giorgos. That's what I just derived while waiting for answers (except I think your inner and outer `type` values should be the same; right now you have a mismatch of `1` and `3`).  It seemed clumsy to me, but maybe it's the leanest option.

Answer (score 2):

I would try this:

```
select type , count(counter) from (
select tbl1.type type,tbl2.expires counter
  from tbl1 left join tbl2
    on tbl1.type=tbl2.type
 where tbl1.type = 1
   and tbl2.expires > now()
) t
 group by type   ;
```

The difference is that in your query you are still returning something when there is no matching data (`if(tbl2.expires > now(),1,null)`).

Comment: Thanks. this works (upvote), bit like The Shooter's answer, it's more complex than the best solution I've found.

Comment: Can you post (edit your question) with the **simplest** answer you found?

Comment: I just posted an answer

Answer (score 1):

You should note that all aggregate queries will return at least single row as result

Look at this example

```
SELECT 1
where 1=0;
```

The above returns empty result. But the following

```
SELECT SUM(1)
where 1=0;
```

Returns NULL as single row

Comment: Thanks. Upvote because it answers the first of my two questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT 
    tbl1.type
    ,tbl1.price
    ,count(A.expires) 
FROM tbl1 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
         tbl2.type
         ,tbl2.expires
    FROM tbl2
    WHERE tbl2.expires > now()
) AS A
ON tbl1.type = A.type
WHERE tbl1.type = 3
GROUP BY tbl1.type
```

#### Edit

Just for your information: Although the above query works but isn't compatible with SQL Server or other SQL Products and won't work there.

Below query would work with any SQL Product which supports inner join and date functions to get the current date. Only change that would be required be to replace Now() with similar function in target sql product.

MySql appears to be linient in some aspects.

```
SELECT 
    tbl1.Type
    ,tbl1.Price
    ,A.ExpCount
FROM tbl1 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        tbl2.Type
        ,COUNT(tbl2.Expires) ExpCount
    FROM tbl2
    WHERE tbl2.expires > NOW()
    GROUP BY tbl2.Type
) AS A
ON tbl1.type = A.type
WHERE tbl1.type = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. This works (upvote), but it's more complex than the solution I've derived. It also doesn't explain how my result from the OP matches my query (which was my first question)

Comment: Thanks for voting the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the alternate query. I have a hard time understanding the order of operations in it. The `INNER JOIN` builds a table first, then we `SELECT` from it at the top right? But is the last line part of the inner query? More parentheses or indentation might help.  I appreciate your time.

Comment: You are right about building the table first. The logic is to first get type and count of non-expire records from tbl2 (without group by it would be faulty/buggy) and then do a join with the parent table tbl1.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses. After learning first from Giorgos that aggregate functions *without a `group by`* always return something, I just added a `group by` clause. Here is my selected query:

```
select tbl1.*, count(*) current
from tbl1 left join tbl2
on tbl1.type=tbl2.type
where tbl1.type=3 and tbl2.expires > now()
group by tbl1.type
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.* , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TBL2 WHERE TYPE = T.TYPE AND EXPIRES >= SYSDATE )  current
 FROM TBL1 T
WHERE T.TYPE = 1 ;

/* IF TBL2.EXPIRES DATA TYPE IS NOT DATE AT FIRST YOU SHOULD MAKE IT DATE *\
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad. I tried to run your query here (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6db6c1/33) but it errors: `unknown column SYSDATE`

Comment: Hi Beetlejuice. SYSDATE is used in PL/SQL . if you want use my code in (sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6db6c1/33) please use CURRENT_DATE instead of SYSDATE

Comment: Thanks. It works (upvote), and it's easy for me to understand.